# Q object in Django Queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-q

I have three vaiables first_name, last_name and middle_name.

To filter the result I am doing

```
Q(contact__first_name__icontains=query) |
Q(contact__last_name__icontains=query) |
Q(contact__middle_name__icontains=query)
```

I instead want to be able to search the query in concatenation of first_name, last_name and middle_name. How can I do that using Q objects ?

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Doubtful with Q, but with `extra` you might try out:

```
SQLite3:
Person.objects.extra(where=["first_name || ' ' || middle_name || ' ' || last_name = " + query])

MySQL:
Person.objects.extra(where=["CONCAT(first_name, ' ', middle_name, ' ', last_name) = " + query])
```

Might not be portable on different DB engines if you start using raw SQL's.

With respect to Q, as quoted in Django site:

> A `Q()` object, like an `F` object, encapsulates a SQL expression in a
>   Python object that can be used in database-related operations.

You can rather change your approach as follows:

```
query = 'MyFirstName MyMiddleName MyLastName'.split(" ")

Q(contact__first_name__icontains=query[0]) &
Q(contact__last_name__icontains=query[2]) &
Q(contact__middle_name__icontains=query[1])
```